# The code gives "Run-time error" 1004" Application defined

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Please I am really new to VBA. but the code below gives run time error. I just need to get the hour of a column.

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("h1").Value = "HOUR"

Range("H2").Formula = "=HOUR(G2)"
Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1UP).Row).FillDown
Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1UP).Row).NumberFormat = "General"
```

Comment: `xlUp` - the letter "l", not the number "1".

Comment: Also you don't need to `FillDown`. `Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=HOUR(G2)"`.